# Arduino JSON over Serial, Json.Parse returning Unexpected JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am building a simple webpage that has data updated via JavaScript DOM manipulation. I want to receive the data from an Arduino, which I accomplished using serialize on Arduino and using SerialPort in node.js.

I am able to console.log the data that comes over the serial as one chunk, which is returned as follows.

```
{
    "day": "Friday",
    "temperature": 288,
    "humidity": 1099
}
```

From my research I figured I need to parse my Json object, but I am getting a

(node: 7759) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse()....

I am very green on this subject, and any help pointing me in the right direction would ber very appreciated.

Node JS code

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', { baudRate: 9600 });
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));// Read the port data

port.on("open", () => {
  console.log('serial port open');
});
parser.on('data', data =>{
  str = data.toString();
  str = JSON.stringify(data);
  str = JSON.parse(data);

  console.log(str.day);
});
```

Arduino Code

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  myFunction();
  delay(5000);
}

int myFunction(){
   StaticJsonDocument<256> doc;
    int temp = 288;
    int humidity = 1099;
    
    doc["day"] = "Friday";
    doc["temperature"] = temp;
    doc["humidity"] = humidity;

    serializeJsonPretty(doc,Serial);
    Serial.println();
  }
```

Comment: I think that your parser.on("data",...) callback gets called whenever the parser detects a newline, not when the parser detects the end of JSON.  see https://serialport.io/docs/api-parser-readline

Comment: Alright, I made some changes and followed the example you linked and I still get the JSON object. But I am still unable to have day, temp, humidity in separate variables, once i try to do data.day I get 5 undefined returned.

Comment: Are you able to remove new lines  from json string before sending?  Then, when your readline parser triggers it might have the whole json string instead of just up to the first new line, which is why it’s breaking now.

Comment: At the moment I haven't found a way to remove new lines before I send it. I was under the impression that the Delimiter would take care of that. I will keep looking, thanks for pointing me into that direction.

Comment: Maybe try [serializeJson](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejson/) instead of serializeJsonPretty?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, thank you all for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was in my Arduino code. I was using static JSON which was not giving me a compressed string.

I switched it to dynamic, as found on the https://arduinojson.org/ documentation.

My Arduino changed to the following.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  myFunction();
  delay(5000);
}

int myFunction(){
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(260);
    
    int temp = 21;
    int humidity = 99;
    
    doc["day"] = "Monday";
    doc["temperature"] = temp;
    doc["humidity"] = humidity;

    serializeJson(doc,Serial);
    Serial.println();
  }
```